# How to maximize the value of binary expression?

Tags: binary, boolean-logic, bitwise-and

How can we simplify `(a&b)*(c&b)`?
where '`&`' is bitwise and also `*` represents product.

Or find b in [L,R] such that `(a&b)*(c&b)` is maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume unsigned. Look at `a & mask` a bit will be set if it is set in both `a` and the mask. A zero in the mask will never make the result larger but could make it smaller, if the corresponding bit in a was set.

so:

`(a&b)*(c&b)` will never be larger than  `a*c` which is achieved when all bits in `b` is set.

If `b` should be as small as possible you could clear all the bits which will not decrement either `a` or `c`, i.e. a bit set in either one of them:

```
b = a | c
```